# Converting month in number to word

Tags: python

i have string

```
date = "2018-09-12"
```

i want to get output like 2018-September-12

and i try like this

```
from datetime import datetime

date3 = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m%B-%d')
```

or `date3 = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%B-%d')`

but always get `time data '2018-09-12' does not match format '%Y-%m%B-%d'`

Comment: What do you expect it to do? The format doesn't match.

Comment: so how can i match format?

Comment: `strptime` is for **parsing**, it has to match the input. You seem to be confusing it with `strftime`, for formatting, and expecting both to happen at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strftime`

**Ex:**

```
from datetime import datetime

date = "2018-09-12"
date3 = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime("%Y-%B-%d")
print(date3)
```

**Output:**

```
2018-September-12
```

- `strptime` to convert string datetime to datetime object.
- `strftime` to convert datetime object to required string format.

Comment: Wow, i second before duplicate, applied, lucky then